# Xpage Tabbed panel issue

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

Actually i am using tabbed panel inside the panel named(tabs).And having menu on clicking that menu link setting viewScope variable .it will passed to " **Tab open by default** "there i am using code like this
 if(viewscope.varaiablename>"")
return viewscope.varaiablename
else 
default tab

i am printing the value passed it shows four time printed same value

please explain me how it will work ![enter image description here][1]

Comment: What is your exact question? Is it not switching to the tab you want or are you worried about the event executing multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
if (viewscope.variablename != "")
```

Did you mean to attach an image also?

Comment: even i tried that also ma problem is when i am partial refreshing that panel .the tabbed panel inside is also get refred for three times .i printed it in log and seen .can you pleas tell me why its triggering three times

Comment: @ Panu it executing multiple times.why it s happening three times

Comment: Sounds like it's executing once for each tab. Please post your code to the question and clarify what you are asking.

Comment: say in menu label click i m setting viewscope.activetab="1" another label viewscope.activetab="2".For the same scope variable replaceing value and partial refresh the panel containing tabbed panel .In Tab open by default i wrote code like this if (viewscope.activetab) return viewscope.activetab else some default tab. when i am printing the what value is coming here that time it printing three times that value .So can you please explain me why its printing 3 times on partial refresh that tab

Comment: @user2028918: The rendered property (which is used for the tab panel) is recalculated multiple times during the JSF lifecycle. That's why it is printed three times to your console. Same thing will hapen with full refreshs.